# CMD Замена подстроки в строке с использованием переменных

Tags: windows, cmd, замена, командная-строка, подстрока

Записываю в переменную `str` путь к папке пользователя.

```
set str=%userprofile%
set remuser=%username%
```

Сейчас `str` выглядит так:

```
echo %str%
С:\Users\pap
```

А вторая переменная `remuser` выглядит так:

```
echo %remuser%
pap
```

Мне необходимо теперь вычесть `%remuser%` из `%str%` и получить путь без имени 
пользователя и последнего обратного слеша:

```
echo %str%
С:\Users
```

Никак не могу сделать замену с использованием переменной, все что у меня получается, это только замена с явным указанием текста, что 
менять:

```
set str=%str:\pap=%
echo %str%
С:\Users
```

Вопрос в том, как тут вместо теста `pap` указать переменную `%remuser%`, чтобы замена была универсальной для любого имени пользователя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы заменить подстроку в строке, используя две переменных, необходимо делать это через вызов CALL, используя, разумеется, двойные проценты:

```
call set str=%%str:%remuser%=%%
```

Тут вы получите путь с обратным слэшем в конце строки. А вот так:

```
call set str=%%str:\%remuser%=%%
```

без него

Comment: Спасибо за просвещение!